# How do I get mailto links in iOS (safari) to open the Outlook app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, outlook

I've noticed that on iPhone users who are using the Outlook app and do not have the native mail app configured, that when they click on mailto links it prompts them to create a new email account in iOS, instead of opening the Outlook app.

Is there anyway to have Outlook set as the default for mailto links on the iPhone?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. I might be wrong though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of 'mailto:' protocol you can use below  protocol to open outlook app

> ms-outlook://compose?to=joe@example.com&subject=Hello

Answer (score 4):

iOS doesn't currently support changing the default apps used for composing email and the like.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate, Already solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33812714/1360730

To test try typing

**ms-outlook://compose?to=a@a.com&subject=aaaa** in the address bar on safari and see whether the outlook app opens up.

So your href would look something like,

`<a href="ms-outlook://compose?to=a@a.com&subject=aaaa"/>`

Answer (score 2):

From the upcoming iOS 14 on, this will be an option that users can set.

> Set default email and browser apps.
> With iOS 14, you can set a third‑party app as the default email or browser app systemwide.

Source: https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-14-preview/