# I just want to open MS Outlook app and see mailto screen using URL Scheme at iOS

Tags: ios, outlook

I got the URL scheme for opening Outlook for iOS (`ms-outlook://`),
but I don't know what is the parameter for getting mailto screen, i.e. `ms-outlook://mailto=xxx@yyy.zzz`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
ms-outlook://compose?to=joe@example.com&subject=Hello
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! Perfect!

Comment: Is there any website with documentation on the ms-outlook scheme for mobile? What parameters and actions it supports?

Comment: `ms-outlook://compose?to=joe@example.com&subject=Hello` this url scheme is not working in Android, how to pass parameters in android?

Appreciated your help, thanks

Comment: Any knowledge about how to add attachments?

Comment: @P5ycH0 Did you have a chance to figure out how to add an attachment?

Comment: @Cam, No, sorry

Answer (score 0):

it is working in Android   :  mailto:XXXX?subject=XXXX&body=XXXX&cc=XXX

Comment: The question is about iOS, not Android.

Answer (score 0):

The most upvoted answer no longer works on the latest versions of Outlook.

Here is the new deeplink :

```
ms-outlook://emails/new?to=john@example.com&subject=mysubject&body=helloworld
```