# Add Calendar Event to Microsoft Outlook Calendar

Tags: ios, outlook

I my iOS app I am looking for a way to give users the option of adding an event to the standard Calendar app, or to MS Outlook Calendar, if that app is installed.

So far I can't find a way to add an event to Outlook. Is there a URL scheme or another way to add an event to Outlook Calendar?

Comment: I know we can add event to ios calender app. Not sure if it is possible to do with outlook app.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri - Yes, I know how to add an event to the iOS Calendar, but this isn't the question. :)

Comment: Did u try creating an event in outlook calender api https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#CreateEvents ? I think outlook app will be synced to this api!

Comment: No, had not looked at the API, was hoping for a simpler solution such as a URL scheme to just pass the date.

Comment: Also, looking to do this. Isn't there a deep drop link to invoke the outlook app?

Comment: @Jiraheta, there is a deep drop link to invoke Outlook, at least for creating emails. The prefix is: `ms-outlook://`. An example to create a new email is: [`ms-outlook://compose?to=joe@example.com&subject=Hello`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33812714/1107226) However, I haven't been able to find anything for accessing the Outlook calendar via URL scheme...

Comment: @leanne yeah, I found the schema to lunch an email online too but not the calendar. I have come to the conclusion it can't be done. I needed to open the outlook app calendar to add an event to it. But I am afraid, it looks like there is no schema to do this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into it and found out this url:

```
ms-outlook://events/new?title=yourTitle
```

This link works for react-native, so I guess its working for native iOS and Android as well.
I haven't figured out the other parameters yet (date, status, description), but I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

SWIFT 4 version.

A few weeks ago I was in the same scenario. So, it turns out that when you add Outlook or Google Mail app to your phone and sync the calendar. A new calendar will appear in your ios native calendar with Caps. So, with that said. You can access the calendar by name and the same way you do with your native apps. This is how I ended up accessing the outlook calendar and adding events to it. Up to this point, I am not sure if the OUTLOOK iOS native app itself will synchronize with the calendar on outlook server end. I am yet to test this. Will update when I verify this.

how do you access your calendars and add event to them, is as follow:

```
//first step 
func isOutlooktAndCalendarPresent(){
    for cal in eventStore.calendars(for: EKEntityType.event) as [EKCalendar]{
        //External calendars appear in caps.
        if cal.title == "OUTLOOK" {
            self.outlookCalanderIsAvailable = true}
        if cal.title == "GMAIL" {
            self.calendarOptionIsAvailable = true}
        //this will be the default calendar.
        else if cal.title == "Calendar"{
            self.calendarOptionIsAvailable = true}}
}

//second step
func presentOptionsForCalerdar(){...}

//third step
func addEventToCalendar(title: String,
                        description: String?,
                        startDate: Date,
                        endDate: Date,
                        branchLocation: String?,
                        calendar: String,
                        completion: ((_ success: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void)? = nil){...}

//calendar step 4
//choose the calendars
func getCalendar(calType: String) -> EKCalendar{
    var calUID:String = "?"

    for cal in eventStore.calendars(for: EKEntityType.event) as [EKCalendar]{
        if cal.title == calType {
            calUID = cal.calendarIdentifier
        }
    }
    let calendar = eventStore.calendar(withIdentifier: calUID)
    if let cal = calendar{
        return cal
    }else{
        if let cal = self.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents{
            return cal
        }
    }
    return EKCalendar()
}

//step 5
func gotoAppleCalendar(date: Date) {... make sure you dispatch this in  DispatchQueue.main.async {...}}
```

Well, that's on a high level how things worked for me. Hope it helps anyone out there.

Comment: EventKit. Calendar access through Outlook app in ios was deprecated a while back. So there is no way to directly deep drop into it. Outlook app in ios creates an outlook cal. You use Eventkit to access that particular calendar.