# Open link to specific email message directly in Outlook for iOS (URI Scheme / Deep Links)

Tags: ios, outlook, deep-linking, url-scheme

I'm trying to figure out how an email can be opened directly in the Outlook App on iOS. The goal is for Microsoft Power Automate to notify my of Junkemails and include a link in the Flow Notification which points to the mail in the junk folder so it opens directly in the Outlook app instead of the webbrowser.

Somehow this magically works for OneDrive web Links. If I click one of those, it opens the file in OneDrive.

I've learned that there's an URI Scheme and Outlook can be opened by links starting with ms-outlook:// and that for example "ms-outlook://compose?to=joe@example.com&subject=Hello" opens a new message as stated here: [I just want to open MS Outlook app and see mailto screen using URL Scheme at iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369198/i-just-want-to-open-ms-outlook-app-and-see-mailto-screen-using-url-scheme-at-ios)

I'm trying to find other commands like how to open outlook e.g. the Junkmail folder or even a specific message. I know it can be done somehow because Microsoft To Do App has this feature. When an E-Mail is flagged in Outlook it appears in the To Do App and there's a link "Open in Outlook".

On Desktop, it opens a web url pointing to that specific email message:
https://outlook.live.com/owa/0/?ItemID=

On iOS To Do opens the message directly in the Outlook App. So somehow it must be possible to create a link which will open the App instead of a Webpage. Of course iOS push notifications for new emails in Outlook also open specific messages.

Does anyone know other "commands" than "compose" like view, messages or inbox or something like this?

I've tried many variations of ms-outlook:// but all of them only open the Outlook App but not any specific folder or email message.

Or is there anyway to look up what kind of link To Do uses when it opens the message in the Outlook App?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have just tested thoroughly almost a hundred of combinations too, but it doesn't work. God know how to build it with the URI scheme... Bases tried : `ms-outlook://mail/0/deeplink?ItemID=` ; `ms-outlook://mail/0/deeplink/read?ItemID=`
; `ms-outlook://mail/0/deeplink/read/` ; `ms-outlook://read?ItemID=` ; `ms-outlook://read/` ; `ms-outlook://owa/?ItemID=` ; `ms-outlook://owa/read?ItemID=` ; `ms-outlook://owa/read/` ; parameters tried : `&exvsurl=1` ; `&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem` ; `&leanbootstrap=1` ; (and combinations) ; `?version=2020051702.05&popoutv2=1&leanbootstrap=1`

Comment: Looks like we are in the same boat. I have been trying different combos for years now. I had hope with ChatGPT and Bing Chat but the examples suggested there did not work either. IIRC it's possible to open a specific email in Apple Mail by entering message://messageId but I really want to open it in Outlook on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Each message has a WebLink property which is a combination of Outlook and unique message ID.

Comment: I don‘t think so. I got the weblink already but it opens in the browser instead of Outlook. If I click on a Link in ToDo it works.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe it's a per app config thing? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-file-links-directly-in-office-desktop-apps-fe241745-9e05-4142-9ba8-1bb1dc044773