# Is it possible to launch the user's default email client from a web page (not mailto)?

Tags: url-scheme, email-client

I'm familiar with `mailto://` links; that's not what this is about.

This is more akin to [Sniper Links](https://growth.design/sniper-link), which are useful to reduce friction in the process of confirming a new user's email address. We've just sent the user an email, and we want to give them a one-click way to go find it.

Sniper Links, as described at the link above, are great for that, but they're limited, in that:

1. The user must have a web-based email service.
2. We must be able to determine the mapping between email hostname and email provider (e.g. "some.guy@gmail.com" should go to the Gmail interface).

Those are *mostly* solved problems. Most people these days do use web-based email, and many who instead choose to use dedicated apps *can* use a web-based client. This is not universal, of course.

Mapping between hostname and provider is sometimes trivial (like the @gmail.com example above), sometimes not (@somecompany.com -> Google Apps is less obvious). If it's not directly obvious from the hostname, an MX record lookup will reveal the truth in the case of Google Apps and a most of the other big names in corporate email hosting. Services like ZeroBounce offer APIs to do the lookup and translation for you, for a fee.

But there are users whose email addresses do not have web interfaces, or for whom the URL of the web interface is not easily determined. For these users, I'd like to be able to bring up their preferred email client (assuming the browser -- or the underlying OS -- knows what it is).

I know that a `mailto://` link will launch the default email client (whether web or app) and start composing a new outgoing message.

From a web page, is there a way to launch the default email client *without* starting a new outgoing message? I'm assuming this would take the form of a URI scheme, but it could also be a JavaScript API call or something else entirely.

Bonuses:

1. Also cause it to navigate to the inbox
2. Navigate, search, or filter such that we're likely to find our specific message (based on sender, date, subject, mailbox, etc)
3. Navigate to the precise message we just sent

Comment: I've now discovered the Apple-specific `message://` URI scheme (https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/message), which, assuming I can determine the message-id of the message we just sent, is perfect -- but leaves me still looking for something for Android, Windows, and Linux users.

Comment: I also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339181/open-link-to-specific-email-message-directly-in-outlook-for-ios-uri-scheme-de -- which seems like a special case of my broader question.

Comment: I now realize that the message:// approach is flawed -- first of all, we send emails asynchronously, so acquiring the ID in the first place would be complex. Second, the user might follow the link before their app has received the message, and I'm not even sure what the behavior would be in that scenario.

Comment: did you figure this out in the end?

Comment: I didn't. Unfortunately, the VC funding draught of early 2023 led me to get swept up in the mass layoffs, and so I left that company shortly afterward.

We did a best-effort instead: if we can from the email domain that the user uses a major public email host (Gmail, yahoo, etc), then we launched a link to that company's web inbox, with some query parameters designed to search for the message we just sent. We got as far as implementing it for Gmail and doing some internal testing, but I never saw it reach production. 

Answer (score -1):

No, that is not possible. Browsers won't open Apps "without" a reason. This could also be a major security risk, if they would do.

Comment: What constitutes a "reason"? The user clicking a link with the specific intent to do this specific thing isn't a reason?

Comment: There are tons of examples of web pages opening apps for any number of purposes, especially on mobile devices (search for "deep link"). Zoom links can launch the Zoom app (even on desktop!). What's so special about composing an email that it's allowed?

Comment: To be clear, I understand that there are abuse scenarios, but those are handled by the browser asking whether the page should be allowed to launch an app, at which point the user can choose to deny, allow it once, or always allow. I can't think of an abuse scenario not covered there.