# How to create a new email from an outlook add-in?

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, mailto

I would like to add a 'contact us' link or button in my taskpane add-in. I tried with a 'mailto' link approach which is not working properly : on the web, it launches the desktop default application ; on iOS, it opens a new email, but empty (no recipient) ; on Outlook desktop, it throws an alert because a web link tries to open a desktop application !

Is there a simple way to just create and open a new mail, in the currently used Outlook app, with prefilled fields, so the person has just to write its requests and send ? Info : my add-in is for Outlook 365 and written in JS.

Comment: Where is your 'contact us' button ?  you mean that he is a command button (https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook?product=outlook) ? or he is into the main html page of your add-in ?

Comment: Precisely in the HTML of the taskpane body ! I am looking for a JS function that could create and open a new mail for example.

Comment: How and where you want that this new email open ? in the compose window?... sorry it's not really clear for me until now .

Comment: I just the answer below. I want to open a new message form, but from my taskpane add-in. It seems it is currently impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

As of Office JS API level 1.6 [displayNewMessageForm(parameters)](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.6/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook) method available. Method opens a form that enables the user to create a new message. If parameters are specified, the message form fields are automatically populated with the contents of the parameters.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Unfortunately Office.js API doesn't provide the functionality you are requesting. The API has [Office.context.mailbox.displayMessageForm](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.html#displayMessageForm) method to open existing message in read mode or [Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyForm](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html#displayReplyForm) to display reply form for existing message; it provides ability to open new form to compose appointment [Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.html#displayNewAppointmentForm) as well, but nothing for new compose form.

If this is something you would like to see in upcoming releases you may describe your scenario at [officespdev.uservoice.com](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/131778-add-in-outlook?page=1)

Based on inability to use Office.js API as far as I can see you have 2 options:

- Use as you described "mailto:" protocol to invoke new compose form (with all issues you have observed)
- Crete a simple "contact us" form collect information and send it to your server with AJAX or server-side technology of your choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use the second option, which sounds the best. Thanks !

Comment: Agreed, the "contact us" page will be simple and intuitive for the user.

Comment: I have created a uservoice as suggested: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/20246932-allow-office-js-outlook-add-ins-to-open-a-new-comp

Comment: Does `displayNewMessageForm` work in web version? In my case it opens a new form in desktop version, but in Chrome nothing happens.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov This functions opens a new message form in my add-in while running on desktop Outlook, however on web does nothing.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov, `displayNewMessageForm` has been added to 1.6 version and it takes only parameters as argument. It opens NEW message form, not the existing one. (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.6/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook)

Comment: @Niko I am very sorry, by some reason I thought we were talking about `displayMessageForm` method. I think I need a coffee ;) For `displayNewMessageForm` try to run it without parameters, try different browser as well. If you see inconsistent behavior, please open new question.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the mobile Outlook apps don't support `displayNewMesageForm` which can be used in other clients to create a new draft email. However you can use the Outlook apps protocol to create a draft email. eg `ms-outlook://compose?to=joe@example.com&subject=Hello`.

Here's an example that worked in the Outlook app on mobile devices.

```
const url = "ms-outlook://compose?to=joe@example.com&subject=Hello";
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 75, width: 80});
```

Found details of the protocol here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42285737/1111659.